# How do AWS ECS container security groups work on ECS optimized EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs

**Background**:

I have several ECS optimized EC2 instances that are registered to an ECS cluster.

**Question**:

If I have an ECS service, running inside one of the EC2 instance, that needs to connect to an RDS database, do I create a security group for the ECS service or do I also have to creatae a security group for the EC2 instance to grant the ECS service access to RDS?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you understand by "security group for only the ECS service"?

Answer (score 0):

I ran some tests and found out that the security groups that are configured in the ECS service task (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_service#security_groups) get automatically added to the registered EC2 instance that runs the ECS service task.

You only need to configure the security group in the ECS service network configuration and AWS will automatically attach that security group to the registered ECS optimized EC2 instance the ECS service task is running on.

Comment: I assume you are using `host` or `bridge` network mode for your ECS tasks? If you used `awsvpc` mode then tasks would get their own ENI and the security groups  would not need to be assigned to the EC2 instance at all.